# Values Not Being Inserted with prepareStatement in Derby Database

Tags: java, prepared-statement, derby

I've created a very simple table, and am attempting to insert into it. The table exists, but nothing I try to insert sticks; the resultSet is always null. I think I'm auto-incrementing my primary key correctly. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
String createGenreTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE Genre (GenreID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS " +
                "AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), genreName varchar(60))";

statement.executeUpdate(createGenreTableSQL);

String prepGenreInsert = "INSERT INTO Genre(genreName) VALUES (?)";

psInsert = conn.prepareStatement(prepGenreInsert);
        allStatements.add(psInsert);

        psInsert.setString(1,"Television");
        psInsert.setString(1,"Movies");
        psInsert.setString(1,"VideoGames");
        psInsert.setString(1,"Animes");


String fetchAllDataSQL = "SELECT * from Genre";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(fetchAllDataSQL);
        while (resultSet.next()) {  //resultSet shows null
            int genreID = resultSet.getInt("genreID");
            String genreName = resultSet.getString("genreName");

            System.out.println("GenreID:" + genreID + " Name: " + genreName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setString` method simply binds the given value to the given parameter index.  It does not actually execute the query.  I believe what you want to do is

```
psInsert.setString(1,"Television");
psInsert.execute();
psInsert.setString(1,"Movies");
psInsert.execute();
psInsert.setString(1,"VideoGames");
psInsert.execute();
psInsert.setString(1,"Animes");
psInsert.execute();
```